# translate a webpage and declutter at the same time? how?

Tags: translation, parsing, bookmarklet, parser, google-translate

Translate: google translate, either with bookmarklet or chrome extension

declutter: Instapaper text bookmarklet.

They used to work together sequentially, but recently Instapaper changed their backend coding of the text bookmarklet I think, that this method no longer works.

I have reading disability, am desperate to find a work around. Thanks!

Comment: What does "decluttering" do?

Comment: What evernote clearly , Instapaper text, readability or pocket do.